# Xpage read JSON context - http POST request

Tags: json, http-post, xpages, http-get, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to read java generated JSON stream created by **out.writeBytes** with  my Xpage. I can get data like getServerPort and others (listed in code below) but when I'm trying to read context with BufferedReader or ServletInputStream I'm reciving errors. 
Any one knows simple way to read stream content like that on Xpage ? **readLine** method returned null.

```
    var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext()
    var httpRequest:javax.faces.contex.ExternalContext =exCon.getRequest();

    print("CallCenter getContext "+String(exCon.getContext()))
    print("CallCenter ContentType "+String(httpRequest.getContentType()))
    print("CallCenter ContentLength"+String(httpRequest.getContentLength()))        
    print("CallCenter RemoteAddr "+String(httpRequest.getRemoteAddr()       ))
    print("CallCenter ServerPort "+String(httpRequest.getServerPort()))

    facesContext.responseComplete();

        //  ONE OF METHODS I've TRIED =============
         var stringBuffer:java.lang.StringBuffer = new java.lang.StringBuffer(80);
         var line = null;                 
         var reader:java.io.BufferedReader = httpRequest.getReader();
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
          }       
             print("Buffer "+stringBuffer.toString());

           // ============================


    } catch(e) {

    _dump(e);
```

fdf

Comment: What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: I get error:JVM: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use BufferedReader while ServletInputStream is in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be one: the stream or the reader.  Instead of getReader() use new InputStreamReader(in); point in to the inputstream  of the context

Comment: Thanks! InputStreamReader returned java.io.InputStreamReader@335d335d (hash)- what is Xpage implementation of Arrays.toString() to get this content in plain string ?

Comment: the toString() method of a Reader does NOT result in the content of the stream as String. There's nothing special in XPages, those are standard Java classes. You do  reader.readline() loop like any reader